# Azure function running inside Docker container: POST request to API endpoint returns 'socket hang up' error

Tags: azure, docker, azure-functions, dockerfile, docker-container

Unable to reach API endpoint inside Azure function running inside Docker container

I'm trying to test Azure function execution inside docker container using

```
 docker run  -e AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true  -p 8080:8080 sharediothub/sampledockerimg:1.1.1
```

The container logs looks fine

```
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebScriptHostHttpRoutesManager[0]
      Initializing function HTTP routes
      Mapped function route 'api/createDevice' [post] to 'createDevice'
      Mapped function route 'api/createTenant' [post] to 'createTenant'

> info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
Content root path: /azure-functions-host
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Host.General[337]
      Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000009DE94FE6'.
```

Here is snippet of my docker file

```
`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS installer-env

# Build requires 3.1 SDK
COPY --from=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 /usr/share/dotnet /usr/share/dotnet

COPY . /src/dotnet-function-app
RUN cd /src/dotnet-function-app && \
    mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \
    dotnet publish *.csproj --output /home/site/wwwroot

# To enable ssh & remote debugging on app service change the base image to the one below
# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:4-appservice
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:4
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true`your text`

COPY --from=installer-env ["/home/site/wwwroot", "/home/site/wwwroot"]`
```

There are no errors in logstream of Function App as well. No exceptions in App Insights too
But when I try to hit POST http://localhost:8080/api/createTenant in postman it returns

```
> Could not get response
Error: socket hang up
```

Please suggest how can I ensure my POST request gets executed.

Comment: While passing the URL in Post - In body of postman add - {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "email": "john.doe@example.com"
} and URL- http://localhost:8080/api/createTenant then run the Postman API check if it gives any output? Also check if the azure function is running correctly by running docker ps command , also check if function is reachable to the port -netstat -an | grep 8080 If none of these work, check if there's any firewall restrictions or if you allowed the docker to connect outside

Comment: Unfortunately no success

Comment: Check your docker logs to get more insights- ocker logs <container_id_or_name> and also check another request such as GET request instead of Post? does the GET request work?

Comment: Check your host.json file and see if the correct port binding is specified there. also check if you have allowed incoming connections to port 8080 of your docker container

Comment: This also might be an issue with the Postman app, can you try this request with another app like Thunder client extension in VS Code , Refer here- https://i.imgur.com/F1XUhPl.png

Comment: Any luck with Thunder client?

Comment: @SiddheshDesai Seems some issue when running container from docker desktop. When I execute `docker run -p 7075:80 repo/image:tag` it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unable to reach API endpoint inside Azure function running inside Docker container

This could be due to the incorrect port mapping or docker container configurations.

Check the port mapping configuration. Ensure that the mapping is being done correctly and the container is listening on the correct port.

***In your case, the default port for Azure Functions seems to be `80`, *not* `8080` as per the logs.***

[image]

So, change the port mapping from `8080:8080` to `8080:80` while running the image in local container.

***As per the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deploy-container-apps?pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=acr,bash#build-the-container-image-and-test-locally),  run the docker image using the below command:***

`docker run -p 8080:80 -it <docker_id>/<imagename>:<tagname>`

The '***socket hang up***' error occur when the server closes the connection abruptly or when the Function app is not running/ not reachable. It happens when the server is overloaded or network issues.

---

- ***Dockerized my azure function and pushed the image.***

[image]

***My function is listening to port 80.***

Tried to run the image by mapping the ports 8080 with 8080, but I was getting error while trying to hit the function API.
[image]

**Response:**

[image]

***Later, tried with port mappings 8080:80, could get the expected response:***

[image]

***Browsing the API after running the image in local container:***

`http://localhost:8080/api/HttpExample`

[image]